# qtdemux missing in gstreamer for an TSN test

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, gstreamer, cross-compiling, gstreamer-1.0

I'm  following a guide in https://tsn.readthedocs.io/avb.html#gstreamer-plugin to create a TSN talker, I've followed the guide BUT croscompiling inside a raspberry pi CM4, this has an ARM64 BCM2711.

Once I have all prepared and execute the last step:

```
sudo gst-launch-1.0 clockselect. \( clock-id=realtime     filesrc location=sintel_trailer_720p_TOVERLAY.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse config-interval=-1 !     avtpcvfpay processing-deadline=20000000 mtt=2000000 tu=125000 streamid=0xAABBCCDDEEFF000A !     avtpsink ifname=eth1.5 priority=3 processing-deadline=20000000 \)
```

I get the following error:

> 0:00:00.038947044 24548  0x153ca80 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE
> gst/parse/grammar.y:850:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "qtdemux"
> 0:00:00.039168794 24548  0x153ca80 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE
> gst/parse/grammar.y:938:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no sink
> [source=@0x158c0f0] 0:00:00.045725632 24548  0x153ca80 ERROR
> GST_PIPELINE gst/parse/grammar.y:938:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has
> no source [sink=@0x1582900] WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element
> "qtdemux"

How can I include or replace the qtdemux plugin?

Where is supposed included this in the gstreamer repositories?

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: well have you installed gst-plugins-good? Check for libgstisomp4.so  What prints `gst-inspect-1.0 qtdemux` without sudo?

Comment: maybe you have messed up installation of GStreamer. There is already nice script which builds and setup everything for you https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-meson.html?gi-language=c   .. its called gst-build. Otherwise debug if you have correctly set GST_PLUGIN_PATH and if in that path are all necessary libraries. Also you can check blacklisted plugins with `gst-inspect-1.0 -b` .. also noticed in tutorial its set `--prefix /usr/local` but GST_PLUGIN_PATH is not set to that..